# Resizing on form load

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I got a problem when trying to load `dataGridView` in new form. In new form I have added new `datagridview` set max size 12;58. But when I loading form its set location to 0;0 in form and if I don't set max size then this grid re-sizing to my window resolution. That's why I set max size but with location still I had a problem.

Code using to fill `dataGridView`:

```
        DataSet d = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(data, conn);
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(d);
        conn.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = d.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Any suggestions what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Notice that you've this statement that will make your dataGridView fully-filled the whole WinForm. Please try to remove that and re-compile your app.